# How to get the current active table (where currently the cursor is positioned) in Word using Office.js api?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I want to get the content of a table ,by just clicking on the table(*not selecting the table*) i.e placing the cursor on the table, in Word Add-in using Office Js Api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Word JS API has (since release of Requirement Set 1.3) the `parentTable` and the `ParentTableOrNullObject` properties of the `Range` object.

Since `document.GetSelection()` returns a `Range` object, code like the following sample will evaluate whether the current selection is in a table. (It also counts the number of rows and selects the table.)

```
    const range = context.document.getSelection();
    range.load("parentTableOrNullObject");
    await context.sync();
     var isInTable = range.parentTableOrNullObject;

    if (isInTable.isNullObject) {
      messageText = "The selection is not in a table."

    }
    else {
      var tblRows = isInTable.rowCount;
      isInTable.load("rowCount");

      await context.sync();
      var messageText = 
         "The selection is in a table with " + tblRows.toString() + " rows.";
      isInTable.select();
    }

    console.log(messageText);
```